# android: location of sqlite database on the device

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created a sqlite database programmatically with the default way of extending SQLiteOpenHelper and overriding onCreate. This way db gets created on the fly when needed.

I'd like to copy the file over to mac/pc to check its contents with an sqlite browser.
I know the name of db file, but can't find it on the device. I've connected to the device via USB, then looked with finder and terminal, just can't find the db file.

What is the default location for sqlite databases on an android device?

pom